# Why does my call to an MVS POST function skip the RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

MVC5

The actual issue here is that my code is working and I don't understand why, which suggests to me I might be using a bad practice. So I wanted to ask for input on this.  This is the code I had already created for my app:

```
Function Method() As ActionResult
  Dim viewModel As New aViewModel
 // Code that sets up the View for a POST…
  Return View(viewModel)
End Function

<HttpPost()>, <ActionNAme("Method")
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Function MethodDifferentName(<Bind(…)> ByVal parameter As Type1)
 // Code that confirms the POST is valid and saves data …
  Return RedirectToAction("<some action after the POST>", "<some controller>")
End Function
```

(Note: When I originally coded Method, the parameter list was identical to the POST method, so I had to rename the POST method.  I don't really need that anymore, but I've included exactly what is working right now so people are responding to the code as it is)

When I created a seed method, it turned out the MethodDifferentName(...) did exactly what I wanted done to seed the database.  So instead of duplicating the code which I thought is bad practice, I simply called the existing function as follows:

```
Dim instance As New ControllerWithTheMethod
.
.
instance.MethodDifferentName(ParameterOfType1)
```

And it works, but I don't know why.  I coded this a couple of months ago and don't remember thinking twice about doing it.  But when I was stepping through the seed code I noticed as execution stepped through MethodDifferentName, it skipped the RedirectToAction().  That caught my attention.

I don't understand why it skips the RedirectToAction().  Can anyone explain?

Comment: Maybe you need to add As ActionResult to the second method?

Comment: I believe you may be giving me the answer, but 1st I think I may have miscommunicated; I don't have a problem with how things are working.  I don't actually want the 'RedirectToAction' to actually function on the second method, I just didn't understand why it wasn't.  But I believe you're pointing out that in the second method, it's not an 'ActionResult' function, so RedirectToAction doesn't work.  Is that your point?

Comment: Well the RedirectToAction is not a method that will switch to another action. It is a return value that results in a http redirect code being sent to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is `RedirectToAction` does not actually redirect anywhere, it just constructs result (which you promptly ignore on return from the function).

I suspect you expect `RedirectToAction` to work similarly to `Request.Redirect(...)` which redirect and terminates processing of the request, which not the case in ASP.Net MVC - all `RedirectXXX` helpers just return `RedirectResult` that still need to be returned from action to be rendered later as actual redirect.

Fix - return result of `MethodDifferentName` from your new action.

On why `MethodDifferentName` does something: unless you use request level properties of the controller in the method you can call instantiate and call such method of any controller. Note that you may be better off making such method `static` (C#) to clarify that it does not depend on controller's properties.

Comment: I believe your comment in the 2nd paragraph is the explanation I seek.  You're right, I expected a 'redirect' type of action, but you have explained that's not the case.  Also see my comment above back to Ron.  I don't really need the fix you propose because I don't need anything back; the method has updated the database and that's all I needed.  Thx!